# I can't navigate to the next page cannot find error

Tags: javascript, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hYd4.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CLeA.png)[import React from "react"
import {View,StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity,Text,TextInput,Image} from "react-native"
import Schoolboard from "../Screen/Schoolboard"

class studentdetails extends React.Component{

```
render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.maincontainer}>
            <Image source={require("../Image/Capture.png")} style={{marginBottom:100}}/>
            <Text style={{fontWeight:"bold",fontSize:20,color:"black"}}>Student details</Text>
            <View style={styles.buttoncontainer}>
                <View style={{marginBottom:50}}>
                    <TextInput placeholder="Full Name" placeholderTextColor="#1d4152"style={styles.textInputViewMob} />
                    <TextInput placeholder="Email" placeholderTextColor="#1d4152"style={styles.textInputViewMob} />
                    <TextInput placeholder="Select State" placeholderTextColor="#1d4152"style={styles.textInputViewMob} />
                    <TextInput placeholder="Pincode" placeholderTextColor="#1d4152"style={styles.textInputViewMob} />
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate("Otp");}}
               
                style={styles.continueButton}>
                    <Text style={{color:"white"}}>
                        Register
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>

        </View>
    )
}
```

}

export default studentdetails
[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN7Qx.png)

Comment: Can you share your Navigation Container ?

Comment: attached as image

Comment: Can you please try by adding constructor in your screen ?

Comment: i add constructor in home screen

Comment: Please try by adding it to studentDetails screen..